# filter based on parent attribute

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I am looking for some help with buliding a LINQ query. i want to get all the Tabs for a particular datatype. I started builind the query but seems like still having some issue. Appreciate any feedback.Thanks Jay

```
  <DataType name="WELL_INDUSTRY">
    <Database key1="key1" key2="" delimeter="">
      <Tabs>
        <Tab>
          <Name>Basic</Name>
```

```
var tabs = from tab in doc.Descendants("Tab")
           where tab.Parent.Parent.Attribute("Name").ToString() == "WELL_INDUSTRY"
           select new
           {
               Name = tab.Descendants("Name").First().Value
           };

foreach (var tab in tabs)
    Debug.WriteLine(tab.Name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, you're starting from the wrong side of the problem. Why don't you find `<DataType>` first, and then select all containing `<Tab>`s?

```
var tabs = from dt in doc.Descendants("DataType")
           where (string)dt.Attribute("Name") == "WELL_INDUSTRY"
           from tab in dt.Elements("Database").Elements("Tabs").Elements("Tab")
           select new
           {
               Name = (string)tab.Elements("Name").First()
           };
```

I would also recommend replacing `doc.Descendants("DataType")` with more *strict* match using `Element`/`Elements` with proper element names. It will make the query faster. I can't do that for you because I don't know whole document structure.